# MYSQL Installation Problem

Tags: mysql, sql, .net

I was downloaded the MYSQL from this link http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

But i cannot able to find the Installation file...

How to create database & Table in mysql? It will work like SQL server or ?

Need  Help

Comment: Are you planning to install mysql on a windows machine or linux machine

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to clarify your question a little by providing more details.  If you are installing on Windows, you will need the appropriate MSI file.  If you are installing on Linux, you will either need the appropriate package, or you will need to download the source and compile it.

In Windows, you can access it from the command prompt via the mysql command.  In Linux, you will need to access it from the terminal, via the mysql command.  Alternatively, you could use something like phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 0):

One more good mysql tool on the windows platform is sqlyog.

Answer (score 0):

> I downloaded MySQL, but I cannot find
>   the installation file.

Locate the default download directory or force the download to save in your Desktop folder.

> How do I create databases and tables?

Use [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/).